# How to use row span in a css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Not sure if what am I am trying to achieve is possible using css grid but the current implementation I have is not working. Below is the layout I am trying to achieve. The box in red spans two rows.

[image]

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 90px);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  width: 516px;
}

.wide {
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  background-color: red;
}

.block {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block wide"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the red box does not span 2 rows. it spans 2 columns!. Simply apply `grid-column: span 2;` to the box

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As said in the comment, you dont span 2 rows, you span 2 columns. Also you need to apply the class to the 1st element: `.wide { grid-column: span 2; }`

In your picture you also have a 6 column grid not a 5 column one

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 90px);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.wide {
  grid-column: span 2;
}


/* for styling purpose only */
.grid > div:nth-child(n+1) {
  background-color: grey;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="wide"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd faced a similar dilemma, but to have two columns instead, then to have some items to span two rows. At first I was using numerical positions to hard-set these, but I've completely overlooked your use of "span". So I've decided to try "grid-row: span 2", and it had worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Following Html and Css you need for grid span option:

```
<div class="grid">
   <div class="col-span"></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

And the Css you need for that is:

```
.grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 50px);
      grid-auto-rows: 50px;
      grid-gap: 5px;
  }

  .col-span {
      grid-column: span 2;
  }

  .grid > div {
       background-color: #fcfcfc;
  }

  .grid .col-span {
       background-color: gray;
   }
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 50px);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.col-span {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid > div {
  background-color: #e9e0e0;
}

.grid .col-span {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-span"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 90px);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  width: 516px;
}

.wide {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 /3;
  background-color: re
}

.block {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block wide"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The following produces exactly what you want.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="block" style="grid-column: 1/3;"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

In the CSS, I deleted `.wide` and `.block`. `#wrapper` was left unchanged.

---

> Not sure if what am I am trying to achieve is possible using css grid

**Anything** is possible using CSS Grid

Comment: Solid! Thanks Thomas!!!

Comment: @user you are welcome!! If you are looking to learn modern CSS, I absolutely love https://moderncss.dev/, great material there! Such as: [3 CSS Grid Techniques to Make You a Grid Convert](https://moderncss.dev/3-css-grid-techniques-to-make-you-a-grid-convert/)